Get epic progression in Jira in a dashboard
I want to create a dashboard in jira, in order to watch progression of my epics. There is a system field in Jira called Progression. For the moment I applied a simple filter for getting Epics, and displayed progression column, here is what I get

Even if I can see the progression percentage when I consult Epic details :

I have the same problem when progression is different of 0%
Thanks for your help
